# Docker package*.json copy failing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to run docker-compose for my two microservices, but I am getting this error. The same happens when using docker build.

```
gateway       | npm ERR! code ENOENT
gateway       | npm ERR! syscall open
gateway       | npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
gateway       | npm ERR! errno -2
gateway       | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
gateway       | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
gateway       | npm ERR! enoent
```

The error is the same for the user service too.

Here is my folder layout:

```
backend/
├── docker-compose.yml
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── apps/
    ├── gateway/
    │   └── Dockerfile
    └── user/
        └── Dockerfile
```

Here is my gateway/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest As development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build gateway


FROM node:latest as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY ./ ./
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/apps/gateway/main"]
```

And here is my user/Dockerfile. It's basically the same as gateway.

```
FROM node:latest As development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build user


FROM node:latest as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY ./ ./
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/apps/user/main"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./apps/gateway/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - ${APP_GATEWAY_PORT}
    environment:
      API_HOST: ${API_HOST}
      APP_GATEWAY_PORT: ${APP_GATEWAY_PORT}
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${APP_GATEWAY_PORT}:${APP_GATEWAY_PORT}
    command: npm run start gateway
  user:
    container_name: user-service
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./apps/user/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - ${APP_USER_PORT}
    environment:
      API_HOST: ${API_HOST}
      APP_USER_PORT: ${APP_USER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${APP_USER_PORT}:${APP_USER_PORT}
    command: npm run start user
```

I've tried changing the COPY source directory using relative path, but it did not work and it is also not recommended. I also tried changing the docker-compose build context, but it did not work eitehr. I also ran docker-compose with --build arg, but no luck.

Comment: Are you seeing this error when you `docker-compose build` the images, or only when you use `docker-compose up` to run the containers?  The `volumes:` blocks overwrite the images' contents with some data from the host system and some from anonymous volumes, and it looks like the paths might not line up.  If the images can be built but not run, does deleting the `volumes:` blocks help?